# truecrypt permission denied mounting network drive

Tags: networking, mount, truecrypt

I have an encrypted file container that I am mounting over a local network (the drive is connected from my raspberry pi) to my laptop.

`sshfs raspi:/media/sda1/true_folder/ /media/raspi`

Then I try to mount the encrypted file through truecrypt (which works when I have the file locally stored on the laptop)
`truecrypt /media/raspi/truecrypt_file /media/truecrypt7/`

When I input the password however, truecrypt says `permission denied` and it fails to mount,

I suspect it has to do with the read/write permissions being specific to the device the truecrypt file is locally owned on. I have edited my fuse.conf to `user_allow_other` but still no success

*edit*
The truecrypt file is on a ntfs external drive mounted on the raspberry pi. Its owner is root

Answer (score 1):

Its a permission issue.

try to run "sshfs" command from root's account and try again and it should work.

The problem you are experiencing comes from a simple fact that the remote file you are trying to access appears locally as owned by the user who run "sshfs" command while truecrypt will attempt to open the file from root's account and this results in the permission error you are getting.

Comment: the issue with that is sshfs is supposed to be user mounted, if not it always responds with `connection reset by peer` [explained here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127270)